# php + mysql чат, вывод новых сообщений

Tags: php

Всем привет, пишу чат для сайта на php + mysql, но столкнулся с проблемой вывода новых сообщений без обновления страницы. Не могу реализовать. С JS не знаком.

```
            <div>
                <div id="chat_container" class="chat">
                    <?php include("chat.php"); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

chat.php

```
            <?php 
                $resulte = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE 1");
                while ($rowe = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulte)) {
                    $user_name = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT vk_username FROM `user` WHERE id='".$rowe['user_id']."'"), 0);

                    $administrator = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT administrartor FROM `user` WHERE id='".$rowe['user_id']."'"), 0);
                    $moderator = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT moderator FROM `user` WHERE id='".$rowe['user_id']."'"), 0);
                    if($administrator == "1"){
                        $nickname = '<span class="nickname" style="color: red;">'.$user_name.'</span>';
                    } else if($moderator == "1"){
                        $nickname = '<span class="nickname" style="color: #13cad4;">'.$user_name.'</span>';
                    } else {
                        $nickname = '<span class="nickname">'.$user_name.'</span>';
                    }
                    $user_avatars = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT ava FROM `user` WHERE id='".$rowe['user_id']."'"), 0);
                    echo '<div class="item_mess">
                        <span><img src="'.$user_avatars.'" class="user_ava"></span>
                        '.$nickname.'
                        <p class="message">'.$rowe['text'].'</p>
                    </div>';
                }
            ?>
```

Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Использовать `AJAX`? `SocketIO`?

Comment: @Саня Горин В данном случае, Вам необходимо воспользоваться `ajax`, с обращением к Вашему файлу запросов в БД. Я так же должен Вам упомянуть, что Вам стоит использовать предзапросы и PDO, чтобы обеспечить защиту от `SQL` инъекций.  После получения ответа от `ajax`данные выводятся через `js`. Чтобы ответить на Ваш вопрос, Вам необходимо сначала его конкретизировать и разбить на атомарные части.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Проблема в том, что я вообще не понимаю js и ajax.

Comment: @СаняГорин Для начала Вам необходимо почитать информации о запросах `ajax` Вот несколько примеров - https://good-code.ru/ajax-zapros/  http://dnzl.ru/view_post.php?id=271. Попробуйте реализовать. Если что-то будет не получаться - смело пишите, Вам обязательно помогут. Другая часть вопроса - это вывод полученных данных из БД в документ `html` при помощи `js`. Так гораздо быстрее Вы сможете не только разобраться самостоятельно, но и получить точный ответ.

Comment: Расширение `mysql_*` устарело, и исключено в пхп 7. Но это в целом вообще ничто, по сравнению с тем, что для каждого сообщения  в чате имена пользователей тут тянутся отдельными запросами в цикле, +еще три запроса на модератора, администратора и аватару.